# How to do System.assert() check of a deleted record

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a simple test class that creates and deletes an account record. With this class I'm testing my account merge functionality.

```
@isTest
public static void testUltimateParent18DigitIDonAccountDelete() {
    // testing after delete action on account merge
    Account dummyAccount = new Account(Name = 'name');
    insert dummyAccount;

    HunleyTriggerUtilities.resetRun('AccountTrigger');
    delete (dummyAccount);
}
```

It works fine and I have the required code coverage. My question is - Is there a way to use System.assert() OR System.assertEquals()? Do I need to use it? Does it make sense to use it?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try query the Account and asserting that with the size with 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could verify the account no longer exists by querying for it, e.g.

```
System.assertEquals(0, [SELECT COUNT() FROM Account WHERE Id = :dummyAccount.id], ‘Account should be deleted’);
```

Comment: That's it, I forgot you can actually put a query inside system.assertEqual(). Thanks!